# Xcode 5 Image Slicing

Tags: ios, xcode5

I'm trying to slice an image in assets Xcode 5. I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible with slicing.

The image looks like this:

[image]

I need to change the width and the height of the image, although not at the same time. The closest I've got is when I use Horizontal for the height and Vertical for the width. The problem is when I change the width, the left side of the image starts as a straight line and the skews and change to the original shape.

I'm about to give up on the idea of slicing and just create three images, left, center and right. Is that the only way to go?

This is how my current slice looks like:

[image]

Is there any way to change it so it works at least for the width?

**UPDATE**

Instead of slicing the image I used a mask and moved the mask.

Comment: You will be able to slice for a varying width but not height. What have you tried with the slicing? Can you show a screen shot of your current slice.

Comment: Thanks, have a look at my updated question.

Answer (score 4):

Slicing works by taking the center section, and stretching it to fill the required space and then putting on the image end caps.

Because your button has a continuous diagonal line you will not be able to slice it. It will stretch the image out like so:

[image: how slicing scales images]

In fact even if you make a centre section and end caps you will still have the same issue as this image can only be scaled.

If you only need a finite set of heights then you should create individual assets for each height that can be sliced horizontally. If you need N heights then you should look into using core graphics to draw your shape in code in a `-drawRect:` method for arbitrary dimensions.

P.S. if you want to horizontally slice so you can grow the width its most optimal to have only 1 pixel width of image that will be stretched out so your button image resources would look a bit like this:

[image: image that is optimal for slicing]

Aha. TIL: You can change the slicing options from the attributes inspector in the right hand pane in Xcode. To make your slicing work choose only "Horizontal"

[image: correct slicing in xcode]

Comment: Thanks @jackslash, that's what I thought :)

Comment: In the attributes inspector you could always change the slicing in the drop down. If I try slice it the way you show, the image will skew when changing the width.

Comment: Can you change the width for that image in an update frame without the image skewing?

Comment: Note that the values in the inspector are purely for demonstration and don't correspond to the image above. I'll change that.

Comment: Here's a `drawRect:`-based solution you could use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12387163/1445366

Comment: @AaronBrager, thanks! I will probably try that instead.